# Entity Framework Code First Migration: Best way to update database with Changes in the model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I am working with Code First Migration based in code and I would like know what is the best way to update my database schema using the changes in the model. In our application we are planning have more than one dataContext for each domain model and also have a legacyDataContext that for now contains all the tables from the database (yes, we are working with legacy database what in the future will suffer changes in the schema).
So If I make changes on an entity that belong to more than one datacontext, wath should I do? 
Run "update database"/ Execute Database.Initialize for each context where this entity is?

Maybe a better idea is have a datacontext containing all the tables of the database and then if some entity(cs class) change in the model, then just update the dataContext that has all the entities/tables.

what is your advice?

Comment: Personally i wouldn't use this magic to update your production database. I only trust a simple and safe sql script where you exactly know what happens

Comment: yes, it's a valid option, how do you work with EF code first and sql script? using: - Update-Database -script -verbose ?
and after that you put this sql script file inside of some kind of sqlInstaller in order to update your production database? I would like hear how do you work using Code First + sql script :)